# Caching props in getDefaultProps an anti-pattern in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a complex react app and using [Cortex](https://github.com/mquan/cortex) as my central model. The philosophy with cortex is that it wraps your data and on changing the data, calls a complete re-render from the root. This works great especially when you have non hierarchical views changing state and affecting the other.

The issue that I am facing is maintaining states/props on re-render. For example I have a certain hierarchy which goes like this:

```
<Page>
  <EditorCard>
     <Editor/>
     <PublishButton/>
  </EditorCard>
</Page>
```

The `EditorCard` needs the JavaScript instance of the `Editor` in order to make changes to the `Editor` on clicking the `PublishButton` (I am using an external library inside `Editor` which exposes methods for editing). Hence the `Editor` on `ComponentDidMount` sets the instance as a `prop` on the `EditorCard` by calling a function passed down to it.

My issue is that when I click the `PublishButton` I change the value of the cortex object which causes a re-render from the root and I loose the props for that `Editor` (since component is already mounted `ComponentDidMount` is not called again).

The way I took care of this problem is by caching of `getDefaultProps`.

Inside `EditorCard` my default props are:

```
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      cachedData: {},
    }
  },
```

And is saving the editor instance as `this.props.cachedData.editor = editorInstance`

This saves props over multiple re-renders.

Is this how `getDefaultProps` caching was meant to be used? On saving props over multiple re-renders am I breaking some of the core react rules with this hack? Could you suggest a better structure if so?

Answer (score 6):

No, `getDefaultProps` is what it means to be: getting the default props in case the owner hasn't passed those to you. You could say it's a shorthand for `a = this.props.bla || 'hello';`.

That being said, if I'm understand your question correctly, I see three ways to solve it.

1. Cache that in your state instead. Props are passed by the parent and are meant to be read from, inside the child, at least in vanilla React.
2. Instead of putting that props passing logic in your `componentDidMount`, why not put it in `componentDidUpdate`?
3. [`ref`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) lets you grab the instance and call its methods directly.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am trying to figure out the right way of doing this. Comments on your solutions: 1. Won't changing state cause an unnecessary re-render? (unless I put some exceptions in shouldComponentUpdate) 2. Yes, this sounds great but again I fear I am not going the react way of doing this. 3. The editor plugin I am using returns a JS object unlike react instance rendering ref useless.

Comment: 1. React's render is cheap. 2. Put this here as a quick fix, because I'm still not sure I understood your problem 100%. 3. Can't you attach methods in the Editor component?

Comment: I've implemented `getDefaultProps` but when I try to access my props in `render` function, the prop I defined turns up as `undefined`. Why?!